# What substance is being sprayed during this scene in Chernobyl?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

In HBO's *Chernobyl* series, after reactor no. 4's meltdown, soldiers ([Chernobyl's liquidators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_liquidators)) splash a light-brown liquid onto the ground, both streets and forest, and for washing vehicles; for this operation they used a variety of means (manned pumps, trucks, helicopters).

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

What is the reason they do this?
What substance are they spraying?

---

@CGCampbell *(from the Movies & TV stack...)* pointed out this [page](http://www.chernobylgallery.com/chernobyl-disaster/liquidators/), where photos described as:

> Liquidators wash the radioactive dust off the streets using a product called “bourda”, meaning molasses" and "Helicopters spray the area with dust suppressant.

Comment: I guess this was just for show, and any substance would be right for it, simple soap, for example. Chemical substances cannot distinguish between radioactive and nonradioactive substances.If instead used for an ongoing chain reaction on the site, it would be some neutron poison, catching and inactivating neutrons to stop the chain reaction and prevent stray neutrons to activate other atoms in the whereabouts.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of different substances were used for decontamination. The substances contained different sorbent agents, including ["сульфитно-спиртовая барда"](https://elib.biblioatom.ru/text/byulleten-atomnoy-energii_2008_v4/p52/) ("sul'fitno-spirtovaya barda" - "sulfite alcohol spent liquor"). As the Russian word "bourda" is used in the OP, probably this was the specific product used (Russian "barda" and "bourda" mean approximately the same, if I am not mistaken, but "barda" is used more as a technology term).